# Have label change to whatever is the value from the prompt windo

Tags: javascript

I'm not having success changing a particular html id with Javascript code when running.  This is the error:

```
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 179,
  "colno": 28,
```

What I'm hoping to accomplish is having "User" changed to the name entered in the JS prompt.

Expected: the user-label id should equal the value (change the html text) as the same text as result_p.

```js
const name = prompt("What is your name?", "")
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let userLabel = "User";
const userScore_span = document.getElementById("user-score");
const computerScore_span = document.getElementById("computer-score");
const scoreboard_div = document.querySelector("scoreboard");
const result_p = document.querySelector(".result >p");
const user_label_div = document.querySelector("user-label");
const rock_div = document.getElementById("lapis");
const paper_div = document.getElementById("papyrus");
const scissors_div = document.getElementById("scalpellus");

function getPlayerName() {
  let name = name;
  user_label_div.innerHTML = `${name}`;
}

function getComputerChoice() {
  const choices = ['Lapis', 'Papyrus', 'Scalpellus'];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length); //Math.floor -> rounds down
  return choices[randomNumber];
}

function win(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  userScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  const colorUserWord = name.fontcolor("green");
  const colorMyWord = " MY choice was ".fontcolor("#00ff55");
  const userWins = " wins! ".fontsize(6).fontcolor("#3300ff");
  result_p.innerHTML = `${colorUserWord}${userWins}  ${colorMyWord} ${userChoice} and the computer chose ${computerChoice}.`;
  user_label_div.innerHTML = `${name}`;
}

function lose(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  computerScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  const colorCompWord = " computer ".fontcolor("#006600");
  result_p.innerHTML = `The ${colorCompWord} wins! The computer chose ${computerChoice} and my choice was ${userChoice}...`;
}

function draw(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  const colorDrawWord = " It's a tie! ".fontcolor("#ff4000");
  result_p.innerHTML = `${colorDrawWord}  The computer and I both chose ${computerChoice}.`;
}

function game(userChoice) {
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  switch (userChoice + computerChoice) {
    case "LapisScalpellus":
    case "PapyrusLapis":
    case "ScalpellusPapyrus":
      win(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case "LapisPapyrus":
    case "PapyrusScalpellus":
    case "ScalpellusLapis":
      lose(userChoice, computerChoice);
    break;
    case "LapisLapis":
    case "PapyrusPapyrus":
    case "ScalpellusScapellus":
      draw(userChoice, computerChoice);
    break;
  }
}

function main() {
  rock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("Lapis");
  })
  paper_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("Papyrus");
  })
  scissors_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game("Scalpellus");
  })
}

main();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

header > h1 {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
}

.scoreboard {
  background-color: #362D2A;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 7px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  color: #F6CF0B;
  font-size: 46px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.badge {
  background: #E25840;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

#user-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: -25px;
  color: #2D4707;
}

#computer-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: -45px;
  color: #03255A;
}

body {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/TbR9G3x.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

header > h2 {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.result {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.result > p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
}

.choices {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.choice {
  border: 4px solid #a0c9e8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.choice:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #a0c9e8;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE <!doctype html>
  <html class="no-js" lang="">
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
          <title>Lapis Papyrus Scalpellus</title>
          <meta name="description" content="">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
          <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
          <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
  
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
          
      </head>
      <body>
          <header>
      <h1>Welcome to the ancient game of Lapis, Papyrus, Scalpellus!</h1>
      <div class="scoreboard">
        <div id="user-label" class="badge">User</div>
        <div id="computer-label" class="badge">Computer</div>
        <span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
      </div>
      </header>

      <div class="result">
        <p>Select Lapis, Papyrus, or Scalpellus</p>
        </div>

      <div class="choices">
        <div id="lapis" class="choice">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/B2vtbGV.png" alt="">
       </div >
       <div id="papyrus" class="choice">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ysz5uYB.png" alt="">
      </div >
      <div id="scalpellus" class="choice">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bx6LLDK.png" alt="">
     </div >
       </div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: If the user enters "John" for the prompt, i want the "User" name on the scoreboard to change to the same name.

Comment: `document.querySelector("user-label");` should be `document.getElementById("user-label");` or `document.querySelector("#user-label");`

Comment: This one too, `document.querySelector("scoreboard");` should be `document.querySelector(".scoreboard");`

Comment: Thanks, Ariel!  I added the "#" to the user-label and it is working.